# Status bar not visible with XIB in iOS - Why?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Apparently, I am struggling to have the status bar displayed in all of the XIBs I have used to present information in the app. Except those, everything else is just fine and works like expected.

1. I have checked under the `Deployment Info` - It says `Default` status bar.
2. I have checked each of the XIBs, they do have `Status Bar` set to `Inferred`
3. Other than these, I went through most of the posts on the Stackoverflow, and tried: In `AppDelegate` : `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = false` - No luck.
4. Then, to see if anyway it works out, in each of `viewControllers` files I did this:

   `override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool { return false }`

   In each of the cases I had no luck producing the results I wanted. Any help?

Comment: Try adding key  View controller-based status bar appearance with value false to info.plist :) WHat this will do is diable the view controller's capability decide whether statusbar should be shown or not :)

Comment: if you create XIB using storyboard?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Nice suggestion, let me try that out.

Comment: @IyyappanRavi Creating XIB using Storyboard? I didn't get you on this - If you mean adding XIB in storyboard - then No.

Comment: @fennec : Just curious to know :) Did it work ??

Answer (score 1):

Use this code,

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

or

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true);

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden {
       // do stuff here..
       UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = false;
    }

}
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

**Objective C:**

**Option 1:**

Wherever you need a status bar

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:YES];
```

Option 2:

- Set `View controller-based status bar appearance`
  (UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance) to `YES` in your `Info.plist`. (YES is the default)
- In your `viewDidLoad method`, call  `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]`.
- Implement  `preferredStatusBarStyle` method

  ```
  (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle
  { 
     return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
  }
  ```

**Swift**

**Option 1**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
```

**Option 2**

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}
```

Comment: why are you posting objective c on a swift question?

Comment: Edited for both Objective C and Swift